# Batch windows command line doesn't work with Jenkins whereas it works manually

Tags: batch-file, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I create a Nunit test with the Selenium Webdriver framework.
When I launch it manually with the cmd.exe, it works :
[image: it works.]

But when i launch it with Jenkins, it doesn't work :
[image: it doesn't work.]

This is how i launch it : (translation : "Execute a Batch Windows command line") [image: it works.]

I gave all rights to Jenkins :
He is allowed to interact with the Desktop :

Translation :
"Open a session as:

- A local system account

  - Allow the service to interact with the desktop)"

[image: it works.]

I also try to launch it with the Windows Session IDs, the error is different, but it still doesn't work.

I have to precise that here Jenkins is run on a Windows Server 2012 (with administrator rights), and I already launch my tests on my personal computer (W7 and W8.1) and there is no problem.

How can I make my test works with Jenkins on this situation ?

Comment: Does the test load a webpage from another machine? Because `local system account` accesses the network with privileges different from a user account.

Comment: I don't think so, I launch a Firefox session and then load some webpages on the same machine

Comment: So Firefox is launched under `local system account` and shows the required page?

Comment: Can you try changing every \ to \\ on the paths? 
also, wrap the second path (to dll) with quotes ""

Comment: I have a "ParserError" when changing every \ to \\, and adding quotes didn't help. Yes @wOxxOm , but I can't see it because Jenkins opens a new session I think

Comment: Did you try adding `cmd /c` to existing command.

Comment: The test is actually well launched with Jenkins, but it fails under certain conditions (whereas it work on my personnal computer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be as simple as the Jenkins agent isn't as fast at generating the page and its contents as your local machine.

Try adding in an implicit wait into your test that is failing.

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

An implicit wait is to tell WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain amount of time when trying to find an element or elements if they are not immediately available. The default setting is 0. Once set, the implicit wait is set for the life of the WebDriver object instance.

Comment: You are the true MVP (I will be able to award my Bounty in 18 hours)